# Search for certain String inside array of objects

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

I couldn't find an answer so I have to post a new question - although it seems to be similiar to few another questions that were asked already here - but to the point:

I have got some list, for example:

```
private static List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
```

It contains objects of class `Book`, where I have got

```
private String title;
private String author;
```

and getters&setters.

Now I have got a new object `Book` (got from webform through parameters/servlet) and I want to check if title of new book is already on list `books`.
If it is already on that list, print some console output. If it is not, I want to add the whole new object to list. In order to do that, I tried to compare titles using regular foreach loops. Sometimes it worked out, sometimes not (sometimes my function cwere comparing two titles in a right way but sometimes not - I don't know why). I know there is a better way of doing this using Java 8. But I'm newbie when it comes to Java 8. Could somebody show me a good way of doing this?

Comment: Your needs is more like as `Map#merge`. Why didn't use a `Map` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't tell why you want to do it specifically with java-8 features, but it could be done like this:

```
boolean isPresent = books.stream()
     .anyMatch(book -> book.getTitle().equals(inputBook.getTitle()));

if(isPresent){
     ...  console print
} else {
     add it to books
}
```

I think that this could be made a bit more generic btw, to have a method that would accept a `Predicate`.

```
private boolean exists(List<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate) {    
    return list.stream().anyMatch(predicate);
}
```

So that you could match anything you like later:

```
 boolean exists = exists(books, p -> p.getTitle().equals(b.getTitle()));
```

Or :

```
 Predicate<Book> first = p -> p.getTitle().equals(b.getTitle());
 Predicate<Book> second = first.and(p -> p.getTitle().equals(b.getTitle()));
 boolean exists = exists(books, second);
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I just want to learn Java 8, so I wanted to do it this way - that's all.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `findAny` and `Optional`

```
Optional<Book> found = books.stream().filter(p -> p.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(newBook.getTitle())).findAny();
if (found.isPresent()){
    System.out.println(found.get());
}
else {
    books.add(newBook);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to be a little fancy and methodical you could create a 'Library' class that inherits or has-a ArrayList. What you need then is an equals function for book that uses String .equals() on the title. The contains method could then call this looping over the elements.

Answer (score 0):

First you must create the getter's & setter's for the class Book. A demonstration of that would be like this:

```
class Book{
    private String title;
    private String author;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
}
```

Now you can do the following to surf through every objects' title and compare it with the newly entered objects' title.

```
    Scanner in  = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
    Book b = new Book();
    System.out.println("Enter the title:");
    String t = in.nextLine();
    b.setTitle(t);                          //optional
    for (Book book:books
         ) {
        if(book.getTitle().equals(t))
            System.out.println("Title exists");
        else
            System.out.println("Title does not exist"); 
    }
```